# phpmailer $mail->Body = ($message) not working

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

My $message is not getting send, it's empty, getting an error 500code. 
    This gets send $mail->Body = "this is your message";
    This doesn't  $mail->Body = ($message);

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// send from
$mail->addAddress('*****@gmail.com', 'sol');
// send to 
$mail->setFrom('*****@gmail.com', 'sol');
//subject
$mail->Subject = "Test email!";


$mail->Body = ($message);

if (!$mail->send())
    echo "wrong";
else
    echo "Mail sent";
?>
<form method="post" action="webtest.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control" name="subject"              placeholder="Subject..."><br>
<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
<textarea placeholder="Message..." input class="form-control" name="message"></textarea><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

Comment: Where you have declared a $message variable and used it without bracket

Comment: name="message" is how I declared the variable. Then used $mail->Body =($message); to be emailed to me.

Comment: your mail sending code is going to run on every page load, you should sperate it from the form

Comment: Add isset on button

Comment: Your `$message` isn't being set anywhere. If you want to use one of the `POST` fields from your form use `$_POST['message']` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than enough problem in your code. First, it loads on every page load which is not recommended. `$message` is also not defined. It could only be defined with `$_POST['message'] until the form is submitted.

According to your code, It will start searching for every content the mailer class required for sending the email and the problem is, it cannot find the `$message` variable.

Here below code will help you from my view of your code. You can also assign variables like `$subject = $_POST['subject']`. It is completely your choice.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$message = $_POST['message'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// send from
$mail->addAddress('*****@gmail.com', 'sol');
// send to 
$mail->setFrom('*****@gmail.com', 'sol');
//subject
$mail->Subject = "Test email!";


$mail->Body = ($message);

if (!$mail->send())
    echo "wrong";
else
    echo "Mail sent";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="webtest.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..."><br>
<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
<textarea placeholder="Message..." class="form-control" name="message"></textarea><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

If there will be a problem even after adding this code. Comment here, I will help you if I can.

Comment: Form is shown on website with no error but the submit button isn't doing anything. It's not being sent to email. Also echo "wrong" or "mail sent" are not being shown.

Comment: I also changed the form action to "#" and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$message = "This is body text"; 
$mail->Body = $message;
```

instead of

```
$mail->Body = ($message);
```

If it is not work means there is other problem.

Comment: It works but I want to have the $message to be a textarea placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not how you get submitted form values. An input field with `name=‘message’` will arrive in your script as `$_REQUEST[‘message’]` so do this:

```
$mail->Body = $_REQUEST[‘message’];
```